# Using a USB 3.0 Type A Male to Male cable with a Type A Female to Female coupler

Tags: usb

My computer's USB 3.0 ports are not easily accessible so I essentially need to extend the port. In order to do this I am trying to use a M-M type A cable running from the computer into a F-F type A coupler which I can then plug my USB 3.0 device into. However, when I attempt this, the device reverts to USB 2 mode.

After testing the pins of the cable and the coupler, I saw that the M-M cable swaps the RX and TX pins but the F-F coupler does not. I attempted to rewire the cable so that the pin configuration would be the same as if it was the computers direct port, however that didn't work.
Is there anything else I can try or is the combination of cable to coupler just not possible?
PS I cannot just use a USB hub instead as the coupler needs to be IP68 rated. The coupler I'm using is the U325-000-IND from Tripp Lite.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Also worth adding is that the device works perfectly when plugged directly into the computer port, but when plugged into the coupler and cable, 3.0 does not work.

Comment: Is the extension + cable longer than 2m? While the max recommended length is 3m, it depends on the quality of the cable, especially wire type and gauge, along with the PCB components and firmware within the USB plug. As to the TX RX flip, without doing so data collisions would occur _(e.g. it's just like an ethernet crossover cable)_

Comment: @JW0914 - The total length from the computer to the device is about 70cm.

Comment: Someone sold you the F-F thingy, right? Demand them to sell you a cable that works with it. A-A M-M cables are a slippery slope, in USB2.0 they were explicitly prohibited, now they're allowed, but they come in 3 different wirings. So the situation is not really improved, the only thing that changed you can no longer claim such cable is a straight scam.

Answer (score 4):

> the M-M cable swaps the RX and TX pins but the F-F coupler does not. I
> attempted to rewire the cable so that the pin configuration would be
> the same as if it was the computers direct port, however that didn't
> work.

You clearly have wrong M-M cable. In specs, there no such thing, people make all sorts of crazy cables, so you got a wrong one.

More, you can't "rewire" the cable easily, without compromising the super-speed signal integrity, it is a very delicate solder job. And even if you manage to do so, 70cm of  cable and two extra connectors will likely kill the signal anyway, or make it marginal, so the link will be unstable.

So your solution would be to search deeper and [find an extender with proper environmental rating](http:///https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Amphenol%20PDFs/04_ALTW_USBconnectors.pdf), or order a custom-made cable.
[image]

Comment: Apparently M-M cables do exist in specs, but only as "debug" cables having *just* the USB3 data pairs but no USB2 lines (including no Vcc line). Some hubs seem to come with such a cable for whatever reason...

Comment: @user1686, yes, you are right. The M-M Type-A cables were introduced in USB3 specs as debug cables. Some HDD enclosures may come with nonstandard M-M cables, likely due to low profile of Type-A as compared to Type-B connectors.

Comment: Passive extension cables are not in the USB spec, but they appear to work for many people regardless.  I agree that rewiring the cable would almost definitely destroy the signal integrity unless done with considerable care and effort.  If the cable is not too big of an investment to gamble with then it is unlikely to hurt anything to try.  If it doesn't work then a proper, spec compliant, active cable should be used.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that USB female to female adapters violate the USB spec, and by violating the spec things tend to stop working.  Under the USB 3.x spec a male to male cable is supposed to swap the Tx and Rx lines, so your complaint on this from not understanding the purpose of these cables.  These are made for host to host communications, and like an Ethernet or serial cable for host to host communications the Rx and TX lines will crossover.  It looks like you are trying to hack together a passive extension cable.  Any extension to a USB cable is supposed to be an active device.  Most people will just use a hub, but boosted cables exist for this purpose too.

The "superspeed" data lines on USB 3.x cables are quite delicate and introducing two extra connectors in the data path without some active device to compensate for it is just asking for it to not work.  This isn't like speaker wire or a telephone cord where you can just twist the wires together and expect it to work, this is a multi-gigabit per second tuned transmission line.  I'm surprised you got it to work even at USB 2.0 speeds.  A properly wired male to male cable would not have the USB 2.0 data or power wires connected.  I don't know what kind of cable that is supposed to be, only that it is not following the spec.

If you want this to be reliable then you need to follow the spec and find an active extension cable.  I don't know anything about this product but it popped up easily enough in a search and it appears to follow the USB spec: https://www.datapro.net/products/usb-3-0-active-boosted-extension-cable.html

That's just an example, again I know nothing about it, I only use it to show such things are available and to give an idea on what they might cost.

At a minimum I'd suggest using any of a number of passive USB extension cables that are on the market.  These violate the spec too but they still appear to work for most people regardless.  One thing is that they introduce only one additional connector interface, not two like you did.  Another is that they will be wired correctly for host to device communications, removing any need to rewire and disturb the carefully constructed transmission line.